NextJs - Error running "npm run build": ./node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/filesystem.d.ts:65:72 Type error: '>' expected
i ran into an error on my Nextjs project and i don't know how to fix it since it's not my fault.
Main problem
This error: ./node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/filesystem.d.ts:65:72 Type error: '>' expected is returned once i use "npm run build", the body of it is:

  63 |     dynamicRoutes: FilesystemDynamicRoute[];
  64 |     nextDataRoutes: Set<string>;
> 65 |     exportPathMapRoutes: undefined | ReturnType<typeof buildCustomRoute<Rewrite>>[];
     |                                                                        ^
  66 |     devVirtualFsItems: Set<string>;
  67 |     prerenderManifest: PrerenderManifest;

I tried to run "npm upgrade", updating Nodejs (actually at 23.3.0, also tried to use an LTS version) since two day to see if any changes happened to next module, nothing happened at all, and i don't know how to fix this.

have you found any solution?

Nope... I didn't find any solution.

What's your TypeScript version? I had these issues on TS 4.5.0; upgrading to TS 5.0.0+ worked.

Thanks, it worked, i can now finally try my build easily!

Downgrading to 14.2.20 worked for me
// package.json
...
"next": "14.2.20",
...

Note none of the 15 subversions seemed to work through 15.0.4.

It worked too yersteday, but i got the second answer...
